# How to use a SQL Select statement with Power Query against an Access database?

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I've got a query that joins 4 tables that I need to run against 4 different Access .mdb files (all have the same schema) so I can compare the results in Excel.  Instead of creating 16 Power Queries and joining them into 4 queries (20 total query objects) I want to write a SQL statement that joins the tables and run it against each of the 4 different data sources.  There's a chance that the SQL statement may need to be updated, so having it stored in one place will make future maintenance easier.

I could not find examples of this online and the way that Power Query writes M for an Access connection is based on one table at a time.  I did not want a solution that used VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Poking around with the various Power Query connectors I found that I can use the ODBC connector to connect to an Access database.  I was able to adjust the parameters and pass it a standard SQL statement.

I put the SQL statement in a cell (C16 in the image) and named that range *Package_SQL*.  I also have 4 cells where I put the path and filename of the 4 Access .mdb files I want to query.  I name those ranges *Database1* through *Database4*.

[This is the configuration screen to set the database paths and set the SQL statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml88v.png)

```
let
    // Get the Access database to work with. 
    dbPath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Database1"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], 
    // Get the SQL statement from the named range
    SQL = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Package_SQL"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], 

    Source = Odbc.Query("dbq=" & dbPath & "; defaultdir=C:\Temp;driverid=25;
            fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;dsn=MS Access Database", SQL),

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
                      {{"Issue_Date", type date}, {"Revision_Issue_Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

As you can see the magic is done in the following line.  I didn't want the *defaultdir* to be hard coded to a folder that everyone may not have so I set it to C:\Temp.  You may need to change it or even remove it and see if it makes a difference.

```
Source = Odbc.Query("dbq=" & dbPath & "; defaultdir=C:\Temp; driverid=25;
         fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048; pagetimeout=5; dsn=MS Access Database", SQL),
```

I made 4 instances of that query and created another query to combine the results.  The query runs as fast as most any other Access query.  I am very satisfied with this solution.  The query can be altered and/or repurposed from the Excel sheet without digging through the Power Query scripts.

*Note that this solution does not use any VBA.*

[image: Here is an example of the output in a comparison layout.]

Edit 3/21/2023:  Here's a connection string example that utilizes a DSN-less connection.  You can find connection string examples like this on https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/

```
Source = Odbc.Query("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
         Dbq=" & dbPath, SQL),
```